# How to get data from instancetype variable in python

Tags: python

I am new in python, in following code form is an instance type variable which prints `FieldStorage(None, None, '{"Email":"admin","password":"admin"}')` I want to access the Email & password key how to get it from instance please help me to solve this.

---

```
index.py
```

---

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print "<Content-type: text/html>"
print
print "<html><head>"
print ""
print "</head><body>"
print form  # prints FieldStorage(None, None, '{"Email":"admin","password":"admin"}')

print 
print "</body></html>"
```

Comment: The [`cgi` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) explains how to interact with `FieldStorage` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FieldStorage` objects can be used like a dictionary. Just use the key:

```
print form['email'].value
```

Or alternatively:

```
print form.getvalue('email')
```